# SSH screen (CentOS) crashes

Tags: ssh, centos, gnu-screen

I use the screen command to run a Minecraft server on my CentOS 6.4 machine.

However, once I end the SSH session, the Minecraft server and the screen will eventually simply stop such that when I come back to check on the server a few hours later and I try to resume the screen sessiom, there is "no screen to be resumed".

I am unsure if this the screen will stop while the SSH session is active or if it is just a Minecraft/Java issue.

Comment: How do you end the SSH session: do you first do a controlled detach from the screen session (Ctrl+A Ctrl+D), or do you simply kill the SSH client? Do the system logs say anything about the termination of the SSH connection? (It shouldn't make a difference, but there might be useful clues as to what happens.) Does the Minecraft server log anything useful? Do you have the same problem when running other software inside screen (try something simple like `watch -n60 date`)?

Comment: I do detach the session in a controlled fashion. Here is dump of the messages log: http://pastebin.com/jUwqN0pL There is some stuff which may be related to this but I am not sure about. The Minecraft logs simply stop when the screen ends. I'll try running a separate screen session with `watch -n60 date` along with the separate Minecraft screen. If only the Minecraft screen fails, then we know it has something to do with Java.

Comment: You throw 2000+ lines of logging garbage at us? Logging which does not answer at all this most important question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a Java issue.

I had Java jdk 1.7 (downloaded from the Java homepage) installed on the server. Instead I've uninstalled it and used `yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk` instead.

Since then the screen has not crashed a single time.